# Workflow status logs report

Tags: sql, report, workflow

Workflow status logs table:
[image]

The first table is what I have, the second table is the result.

How to make it? help please.

```
RequestStatusLogs table: 
Id
UserFK
PreviousStatusFK
CurrentStatusFK
TimeStamp
IP
RequestFK
Comment
AudienceType
```

Comment: It is very hard to predict the logic required just from table output. Please add some detail about your requirement. Some required fields are understandable and some of them are not.

Comment: i have this table of  
Id
UserFK
PreviousStatusFK
CurrentStatusFK
TimeStamp
IP
RequestFK
Comment
AudienceType

Comment: Still needs a logic like how draft value is "19" in result table? Is the table shared has all values or only snap of the table is posted? Similar way other fields too.

Comment: Jaber, I suggest you write your case in sqlfiddle.com first, so we do our simulation to solve and apply the query for the result for you there easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the code as per my interpretation from the just table output. This is not complete answer.

```
Select Count(RequestReview),Count(CompleteReq),Count(CompleteReq1) FROM InputTable Group By RequestFK
```

Comment: this will give us how many time it go back to the status for one request i want the time interval it stay on this status thank you bro